# C# Mongodb Find the closest time in collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

I have a collection with `DateTime` in it.

```
public class Trade
{
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiary { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the c# driver, and I want to get the closest Expiry from the `Trade` collection.
Is possible in mongodb to bring the closest dates to a given date?
**Update**
something like

```
collection.FindClosest(x => x.Expiary , DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, "closest date" could be considered like:

```
        var record = tests.Find(p => p.Date <= closestTo)
            .SortByDescending(p => p.Date)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Surely there could be a document with a date 'closer' to what you are looking for at a higher bound, but 'future' to your filter, in which case you would skip and fetch the closest older. If your requirement really demands you get that item, I must say I'm unaware of a 'Mongo way' in doing that. It could be done by running this query twice, the second time with the order inverted (and .Date > closestTo) and verify in-process which of the two objects is the closest.